# Seeded database key values conflicting with factory bot create/build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Our rails database is pre-seeded with some data for a few of our static models.  For example, we have a `DocumentType` model that gets populated/updated through `db/seeds.rb`.  Users can't modify this model.

This doesn't seem to play nicely with factory_bot, however; when I try to :

```
create(:document_type)
```

I get an error stating:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
>    PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "document_types_pkey"
>    DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Every time I run the test, this error occurs but the key (id) that is attempted to be save increments.  Then, eventually, the test passes when it's outside the range of the seeded data.

What I don't understand is why factory_bot is actually setting the `id` value and not letting the database assign it when the record is saved.

#### document_type factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :document_type do
    label 'Alien Spacecraft License'
    description 'It should be obvious, I think'
    created_at { Time.now - 30.days }
    updated_at { Time.now - 30.days }
  end
end
```

#### attempted fixes

What I have tried is creating a fixture file that imitates exactly what is in the seeds.rb file -- when I do this, factory_bot honors the `id` values set in the fixture.  But it causes a lot of duplicate efforts (I have to keep the seeds in sync with the fixtures).

I have looked at using the fixtures to populate the database but, unfortunately in our case, we are using hard-coded IDs in the seed data to insert/update ... so fixtures don't seem like a good seeding option.

Am curious if anyone has any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need seeded data in your test db? Generally this is something you'd want to avoid having any data in the db at the start of your test, other than data specified in the test. Have you checked out the DatabaseCleaner gem?

Comment: how did you define your `document_type` factory ?

Comment: @sovalina - I added the factory to the question, thanks

Comment: @PaulByrne - I haven't checked out that gem.  Will do, thanks!  I think if I were to go back 5+ years on this project we might have handled the seeded data differently; as it is, we have the model ids hardcoded in the source API to reference certain models that are expected to be there ... which means we need to have the seeds with the "correct" ids.  In retrospect this seems bad.  Probably should have used a non-incrementing unique field (like a slug).  But as it is, our production serve is getting seeded with data expected to be there and methods reference those specific IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try to sequence your `document_type` factory id to start increment after the last id of your seed

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :document_type do
    sequence(:id) {|n| n + 30 } #i.e n + last id known in seed
  end
end
```

Comment: To make the `+ 30` dynamic, consider something like this: `id { Model.maximum(:id) + 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this assumption is wrong:

> What I don't understand is why factory_bot is actually setting the id value and not letting the database assign it when the record is saved.

FactoryBot is not setting the ID. It's the database's autoincrement which is wrong. By setting IDs by hand, the autoincrement value is not increased alongside it. So, it's still set to `1` even though you've used up that value.

To this fix, after loading my fixtures, I manually recalculated the sequence number:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT setval('#{klass.sequence_name}', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #{klass.table_name}))")
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks!